# Will ENTRY(symbol) command always place the instruction at symbol at the beginning of the .text section?

Tags: linker, ld

According to the [Using ld doc](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_24.html#SEC24):

> The linker command language includes a command specifically for
>   defining the **first** executable instruction in an output file (its entry
>   point).

How to understand the **first** here? Is it *logically* the first instruction to jump to? Or it is *physically* the first instruction to place in the `.text` section?

I use below linker script from [here](https://github.com/smwikipedia/EwokOS/blob/master/kernel/EwokOS.ld) as experiment:

```
ENTRY(__entry)  /* <=============== HERE, the __entry  */

/*kernel will be loaded at this address after boot*/
INCLUDE linker.ld

SECTIONS
{
    /*kernel will be compiled with virtual address base at 2GB*/
    . = 0x80000000 + start_address; /*2GB + start_address = (0x80010000)*/
    PROVIDE(_kernel_start = .); /*defined at kernel/include/kernel.h, set to 0x80010000*/

 .text : AT(start_address) 
    {
        *(.text)
    }

    .data : 
    { 
        *(.data) 
    }

    .bss : 
    { 
        *(.bss COMMON)
    }
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE(_fb_start = .); 
    . += framebuffer_size;

    PROVIDE(_kernel_end = .); /*defined at kernel/include/kernel.h*/
}
```

I tried to search for the instruction bytes at the `__entry` in the final built binary. And found that those instructions are indeed located at the beginning of the `.text` section.

So does it mean the `ENTRY()` command **always** place the entry point at the beginning of the final binary's `.text` section?

Comment: I found the reason. I will explain it later.

Answer (score 1):

The **first** machine instruction in executable file means the instruction which is **executed** first. It doesn't have to be the first one (with the lowest offset) from the ordered list of all instructions in *.text* segment.

Many programs are written in natural  *top-down* style and their **entry** indeed points to the physically first instruction (at offset zero). However  program code may also start with helper subroutines and its entry point will be shifted deeper in code in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The `ENTRY(__entry)` will record the VMA location of the `__entry` symbol in the final object file. For example, in ELF header. After the loader loads each *section* of the object file into the memory, the loader or runtime will just jump to the entry point.

But in my scenario, the `ENTRY(__entry)` is actually **not necessary**. Because the EwokOS runs on bare machine and there's no loader. As I tried, if I commented out the `ENTRY(__entry)`, the EwokOS still can boot on a bare metal.

The reason that the first instruction of `__entry` happens to be the first instruction of the final `EwokOS.bin` file, is a combination of two factors:

- the input order of the object file to the linker `ld`
- the coding order in the `boot.S` file.

There are 3 files fed to `ld` in the order of `boot.o system.o context.o`. So we can see `boot.o` is the **first** object file to link.

And the the `boot.S` file, which assembles into the `boot.o` contains the `__entry` as the **first** line of code.

These 2 factors lead to the result that `__entry` is at the beginning of the final `EwokOS.bin`, whihc is extracted from the `.text` section of the `EwokOS.elf`.

And in my scenario, I need the `__entry` to appear at the beginning of the `EwokOS.bin` file because the bin file is loaded at the 0x10000 address, which is the start address of the QEMU ARM versatilepb virtual machine.